# Adding a Consumer tag for your consideration

Tags: discussion

I was wondering if it is possible to have a consumer tag to be created.

The consumer tag will be tagged to questions related to consumer electrical devices.

Since questions on consumer electrical devices are prohibited in here and currently there is no consumer electrical devices stackexchange ready yet, the consumer tag will be pretty useful.

So, once the [consumer electrical devices stackexchange](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/33064/consumer-electronics) is ready, all the questions tagged to consumer tag can then be migrate to the consumer electrical devices stackexchange.

For your consideration.

Comment: As a side note, do you realize how long that proposal has been idling? Unless someone manages to get a large group of people interested suddenly, that site will not make it.

Comment: @Kortuk. Kind of sad that many good proposal goes down to drain due to lack of a large group of people interest. I was just wondering which site exchange would except consumer electrical devices questions.

Comment: I actually support that proposal to ideally reduce confusion on where to post such questions.

Answer (score 3):

Migrations can not be done post a pretty short timer([60 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151890/disable-migration-for-questions-older-than-60-days)).

Starting a site with a mass migration is considered a bad idea, the community should focus on what they would like to be, if there are on topic questions other places they should stay. If they are off-topic such a question will very rarely be of a quality migration makes sense for a new site.

Comment: Hi Kortuk, I do agree with your answer but I was wondering where is the "other places" that could accept 'Consumer Electrical Devices' questions.

Comment: @Jack I actually dont know an SE, I am sure there are many many old-style forums that do

Answer (score 0):

Nooooooooo!

This site is about electrical engineering and real electronics (resistors, capacitors, opamps, etc).  We already get enough questions about consumer electronics that we have to close.  They are noise here, don't belong, and would seriously degrade the site if allowed.  Having a tag for them is therefore pointless at best since any such question shouldn't be here in the first place and has to be closed.  We don't want to appear to give legitimacy to something that doesn't belong.

Comment: It looks like you may have misread his post, he is asking if we can tag them for migration when the site opens, he realizes they are off topic. I have been tempted before to add the tag so that it would be easier to spot off topic, but any question related to the design of consumer electronics would probably tag that way also, which would be valid questions and the tag would be a meta tag, a tag that does not define a problem but just shows us a subgroup of problems, so I resisted. :)~